# Highest card wins is my program and now I want to compare cards

Tags: java, arrays, function, compareto

I am using Android studio for my highest card wins Game. I have three java classes called Cards, Deck, Gamelogic. everything is going good so far but I am just having a little trouble starting a function for my comparing cards method. This is what I have so far ...

```
import android.graphics.Color;

/**
 * Created by azib2 on 12/1/2016.
 */
enum Suite {
    Heart, diamond, spades, clubs;

    public String toString()

    {
        switch (this) {
            case Heart:
                return "Heart";
            case diamond:
                return "diamond";
            case spades:
                return "spades";
            case clubs:
                return "clubs";
            default:
                return "Wrong type";
        }

    }

    public String symbol(){

        switch (this) {
            case Heart:
                return "\u2764";
            case diamond:
                return "\u2666";
            case spades:
                return "\u2660";
            case clubs:
                return "\u2663";
            default:
                return "Wrong type";
        }
    }


    public int colors() {
        switch (this) {
            case Heart:
            case diamond:
                return Color.RED;
            case spades:
            case clubs:
                return Color.BLACK;
        }

        return 0;
    }

}
public class Cards {
    private int cardnum;
    private Suite suitetype;


    public Cards(int cardnum, Suite suitetype){
        this.cardnum = cardnum;
        this.suitetype = suitetype;
    }
    public String CardType(int num){
        switch(num){
            case 1: return "A";
            case 2: return "2";
            case 3 : return"3";
            case 4: return "4";
            case 5: return "5";
            case 6: return "6";
            case 7: return  "7";
            case 8: return "8";
            case 9: return "9";
            case 10: return "10";
            case 11: return "J";
            case 12: return "Q";
            case 13: return "K";
            default: return " error invaild ";
        }

    }
    public void CompareCards(){

    }

    public int Getcardnum (){
        return cardnum;
    }
    public Suite getsuite(){
        return suitetype;

    }
}
```

What should I do to compare cards?

Comment: Well before you get to the technical details of writing the `CompareCards()` function you could think about what it should do in a general sense. E.g., where would it be called from? What would its inputs be? Should it perhaps take a card instance as input and return a boolean indicating whether that card is higher than the `this` card (similar to how an `.equals()` function might work)? Or...? (Also, I've removed the "javascript" tag from your question: JavaScript != Java.)

Comment: Will Ace be highest or lowest?

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend "Cards" be "Card".  But I'll stick with "Cards" here.

This seems like a good use-case for [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface:

```
public class Cards implements Comparable<Cards> {

    // Ace lowest:
    public int compareTo(Card other) {
        return Integer.compare(cardnum, other.cardnum);
    }
}
```

Then to see if one card is higher than another:

```
if(card.compareTo(otherCard) > 0) { ... }
```

With this approach, you could even sort a list of cards using:

```
List<Cards> cards = new ArrayList<Cards>();
// Add all cards desired
Collections.sort(cards);
```

If you want stable sorting (by both value and suit):

```
public class Cards implements Comparable<Cards> {

    // Ace lowest:
    public int compareTo(Card other) {
        // Compare by value first
        int diff = Integer.compare(cardnum, other.cardnum);
        if(diff != 0) return diff;
        // Compare by suit
        return suitetype.compareTo(other.suitetype);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped. Your amazing.